# random crash in our node app with fatal error

Tags: node.js, v8

my node program is crashing with the following error. Tried on both node v14.18.1 and v16.13.0.

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: i::kMaxInt >= len.
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffd97a48d20
 1: 0xaa6321  [node]
 2: 0x1a3b274 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0xbcec79 v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int) [node]
 4: 0xb1c319  [node]
 5: 0xa14671  [node]
 6: 0xc238db  [node]
 7: 0xc24e86  [node]
 8: 0xc25506 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 9: 0x1446459  [node]
```

Comment: What's your question? How can we possibly help you if we can't see what code causes this crash? Please familiarize yourself with [ask].

Comment: Can you check if the value is between the safe ranges using `Number.MIN_VALUE` , `Number.MIN_VALUE` and `Number.isFinite()` where there could be a possibility of a too big number or `${your number}.toFixed(7)` if there can be too many decimals.

Comment: @esqew we launched a new version of our mobile app and websocket request from app is crashing the server randomly. Even I'm not sure what's causing the crash but I'm thinking it's something related to socketio. Ive set the maxhttpbuffersize on socketio to 10mb but no use

Comment: I know it's a very vague question but I'm not sure which part of the code is crashing the server. Also is it possible to catch this error and collect more logs ? I tried beforeExit event on process but it's not going into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's `v8::String::NewFromUtf8` on the stack, and `Check failed: i::kMaxInt >= len` in the error message, it's pretty clear that your string is too long. On 64-bit platforms, the max string length that V8 supports is ~536 million characters.

Comment: I'm using socketio and have set the maxhttpbuffersize to 10mb. If it's greater than 536 million characters wouldn't that drop the data from reaching the server.

Comment: I don't know where the strings in question are coming from, so I also don't know whether socketio or its maxhttpbuffersize has anything to do with it. What I can tell you is that with a 10MB string, this crash wouldn't happen.

Comment: Found it. It was a rouge db query which was returning 2.5GB of data in response